# Typeahead error: Cannot read property 'inject' of undefined

Tags: meteor, typeahead.js

I'm trying to add `sergeyt:typeahead` to my Meteor project. The following is my code in the `main.js`:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
  Meteor.typeahead.inject();
});
```

The error I'm getting is:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'inject' of undefined`

I've added the package and restarted the server, still the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the main.js file on the server or the client? Can you change the arrow function to a regular function call? `Meteor.startup(function() { Meteor.typeahead.inject(); });`

Also, are you sure the package has been added?

Comment: Main.js is on the server. I tried `Meteor.startup(function() { Meteor.typeahead.inject(); });` and it gives the same error. Tried adding the package and it says it's already there.

Comment: This package does not seem to export anything to the server. `Meteor.typeahead` seems to be client-only.

Comment: @Sean do you mind helping me with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179641/rendering-a-template-from-the-imports-folder-in-meteor  ... Thanks a lot.