# Rendering a template from the imports folder in Meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, autosuggest, meteor-easy-search

From what I understand, the purpose of the `imports` folder is to store all your code that you import into `main.js` in the `client` folder. I'm trying to implement `easysearch:autosuggest` and I got a basic example working with the following in my `main.html` on the client folder:

```
<body>

  <div id="render-target"></div>
    <div>
        {{>searchBox}}

    </div>
</body>

<template name="searchBox">

    <div class="autosuggest-component">
        {{> EasySearch.Autosuggest index=PlayersIndex}}
    </div>

</template>
```

In my `main.js` in the client folder I'm importing `App` from my `'../imports/ui/App.js'` and rendering it:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

 render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));

});
```

So I've tried pasting the template in `main.html` into the `render()` function inside `App.js` in the imports folder, however this gives me an `unexpected token` error pointing to `{{>searchBox}}`. I'm new to Meteor/node and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, also trying to understand if I'm doing things correctly from a structural standpoint. If I have to build my app client side, what's the point of the imports folder? How can I get this to work using `App.js` and `render()`?

Comment: Are you using Blaze(Meteor's own frontend rendering system) and react.js together on purpose?

Comment: @TomScholz No, I'm just following the To Do tutorial from the Meteor website (using react - https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app). Is what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend that you first make yourself familiar with [react](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react) and then start over with the tutorial. You can't render just plain Blaze templates in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are mixing two front end libraries together.

A frontend library is a tool we can use to help us build the user interface of our applications. Some popular ones that people use with Meteor are Blaze, React and Angular.js

The syntax you are using `{{>searchBox}}` is syntax used by the Blaze library to render a Blaze template.

However, in your `Meteor.startup()` block you are using code needed by React. You've also indicated that you have been following the React tutorial. Unfortunately, you can't mix the two of these.

I suggest you start again and [follow this tutorial instead](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). It's the exact same tutorial you've already been doing but it's the Blaze version - which will work with the syntax you've been using - `{{>searchBox}}`

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. Would you mind taking a look at this question when you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183231/react-search-basic-example/49183397#comment85373630_49183397 ... really appreciate all the help.