# React-search basic example

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to get [react-search](https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-search) to work in my Meteor app. This is my main App.js in the imports folder:

```
import Search from 'react-search';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
class App extends Component {
...
render() {
let items = [
  { id: 0, value: 'ruby' },
  { id: 1, value: 'javascript' },
  { id: 2, value: 'lua' },
  { id: 3, value: 'go' },
  { id: 4, value: 'julia' }
]
console.log(items)

return (
  <div class="">  
    <Search items={items} />
  ...
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Once I insert the `<Search items={items} />` my app stops working and I get the following console errors:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I really dont know if this is the cause of your issue, but based on the code provided should be an issue. Your div seems to not be closed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, the div was closed later on. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a look on their source code: https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-search/blob/master/src/Search.js

`import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'`

React had a break change where `PropTypes` is no longer inside the react package.
It's in `prop-types` package now. eg: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

If you still want to use this package, you have to match the dependency in https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-search/blob/master/package.json

However, the implementation for this package isn't hard. So you highly recommend you create your own component based on their code if needed.

Does this help?

Comment: So to do that I uninstall my current version of react and install `"react": "^15.4.1",` to fix this error?

Comment: Ok, I changed react and react-dom to match the source code version. The problem now is that it's not showing properly as it is in his example: https://imgur.com/a/t4PAk . Do I have to have all those packages with those exact version numbers for it to act properly, or how can I figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @Rew I would match `react`, `react-dom` and `babel` related packages first, since these are tied together.

Comment: So this is what my dependencies look like now: https://imgur.com/a/6Ui1N . I tried uninstalling @babel/runtime but then then Meteor wouldn't start at all. I'm still getting the same behaviour. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm now thinking, this `react-search` package might uses older React then the Meteor you're using, and it haven't update for every long time. I strongly suggest you copy the source code to you project, and fix PropTypes in your copy. Or simply remove all `PropTypes` checking. It just a type checking, and will not affect the behavior.